# Do variable declarations become properties of window in ecmascript 6 modules?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

In ECMAScript 5 and below, `var` declarations at the top level of a script become globals, which is to say, properties of the global object (`window` in browsers.) In ECMAScript 6, we now have modules. Modules are in strict mode, so we won't automatically create a global by forgetting `var`, but if I declare a `var` at the top level of a module, does it become a global property of the `window` object? What if I use `let` or `const` or any of the new declaration forms added in ES6?

```
var foo = {};
console.log(window.foo === foo); // true or false?

let bar = {};
console.log(window.bar === bar); // what about this?
```

Comment: @Bergi: I don't think this is a duplicate. That questions asks about `let` in script context. This question asks about `var` in module context.

Comment: Is there a useful way I can edit this question to call out the distinction? I don't feel it's appropriate to just add "note, VAR in a MODULE context", (or something,) because that's basically just rude toward the moderators. But I'm not sure how to clarify that distinction harder in a way that makes it naturally part of the question.

Comment: This looks closer to a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961255/is-there-an-es6-module-scope-equivalent-to-window?rq=1 though there are subtle differences. (I'm asking if they go on `window`; That question is asking if there's _something_ like `window` for modules. The answer to both is the same.)

Comment: Oh right, I'm sorry. Must have been tired :-/

Comment: No problem. It's a subtle difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but if I declare a var at the top level of a module, does it become a global property of the window object? What if I use let or const or any of the new declaration forms added in es6?

The answer is no in both cases. Global properties are created (if [CanDeclareGlobalVar](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-candeclareglobalvar) returns `true`) only for declarations of *script* (section [15.1.8](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-runtime-semantics-globaldeclarationinstantiation)). But both `VarDeclaredNames` and `VarScopedDeclarations` within the module belong to that module (`ModuleItem`, to be precise) - not the whole script.

Be it otherwise, the whole idea of encapsulating data within the modules (so that each module would communicate with the rest of app via established `export/import` routines) would have been just wasted.

Comment: I can't understand the spec-ese, I don't see where in 15.1.8 it checks for script vs module. I guess I need to level up first. Your plain English "if it did, modules would be worthless" makes a lot of sense though.