# Is there an es6 module-scope equivalent to `window`?

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6

In Javascript, we can add global variables at any point using the window object:

```js
'use strict';
var a = 1;

function test() {
  window.b = 2;
}

test();
console.log(a); // a
console.log(b); // b
```

Is there a similar (or non-similar!) way to do assign vars to the current module scope in ES6?

Thanks

Comment: Fortunately there is no.

Comment: Check http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html scroll to `The global object`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Module environments](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-module-environment-records) consist of so called *declarative* environment records:

> A module Environment Record is a declarative [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-environment-records) that is used to represent the outer scope of an ECMAScript Module.

In contrast to the global environment consist of an *[object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-environment-records)* environment record:

> Each object Environment Record is associated with an object called its binding object. An object Environment Record binds the set of string identifier names that directly correspond to the property names of its binding object.

---

Just like with function environments (they are also declarative), there is no way to access the scope from another scope.

Comment: Thanks for the spec reference!

Comment: That last claim may need explaining, because even if you can't "access" one scope from another, there are plenty of examples in which something capture its own scope and then pass that along as a variable for use in another scope. I.e. creating an arrow function that returns `this`. Is the scope visible to the module itself?