# Javascript - How to run an imported function when using window[funcName]?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is imported like this:

```
import { myFunc } from './myFunc.js';
```

I am trying to run this function using a string as the function name (the contents of the string may change):

```
let fnStr = "myFunc";
let fn = window[fnStr];
fn();
```

However, `window[fnStr]` cannot find the imported function.

Comment: have you exported myFunc from myFunc.js file?

Comment: Yes I have exported it.

Comment: This is not possible. ES6 modules use "declarative environment records". see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32963971/3581485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't, because they aren't properties of the global object (which is referenced via `window` on browsers). They aren't globals at all. Which is a Good Thing.™ :-)

You could create your own object with those functions on it, and use it instead:

```
import { myFunc } from './myFunc.js';

const funcs = {
    myFunc
};
```

Usage:

```
let fnStr = "myFunc";
let fn = funcs[fnStr];
fn();
```

---

If you have several of these functions, you might want to export them on an object rather than as individual bindings, e.g.:

`myFuncs.js`:

```
function myFunc() {
    // ...
}
function myOtherFunc() {
    // ...
}

export default {myFunc, myOtherFunc};
```

then

```
import funcs from './myFuncs.js';

let fnStr = "myFunc";
let fn = funcs[fnStr];
fn();
```