# How to import non-module(!) JavaScript into Polymer 3.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, mapbox-gl, polymer-3.x

Polymer 3 uses import to load external Javascript. For example

```
import {GoogleCharts} from 'google-charts';
```

However, it seems for this to work, the external library should use exports.

I am trying to use mapbox-gl.js library. This library, installed with:

```
npm install mapbox-gl
```

does not seem to export anything.

In HTML5, you can use mapbox-gl as follows:

```
<script src="node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
   const options = {...}
   const map = new mapboxgl.Map(options);
</script>
```

I tried to use 'import' to load mapbox-gl:

```
import {mapboxgl} from './node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';
import mapboxgl from './node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';
```

This doesn't work:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js' does not provide an export named 'mapboxgl'
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

So, then I tried to add the script and css to document.head from inside the **module** javascript (`<script type="module">..</script>`):

```
// load external mapbox-gl.js script
const mapboxgljs = document.createElement('script');
mapboxgljs.setAttribute('src', 'node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');
document.head.appendChild(mapboxgljs);
// load external mapbox-gl.css 
const mapboxcss = document.createElement('link');
mapboxcss.setAttribute('href', 'node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css');
mapboxcss.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
document.head.appendChild(mapboxcss);
```

This does not seem to work either. If I try to use mapbox as follows:

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map(options)
```

I am getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined
```

**Edit:**

Commenters @Salketer and @barbsan showed correct import syntax for this kind of library:

```
import 'node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';
```

or

```
import * as mapboxgl from 'node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';
```

Both now result in the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mapboxgl' of undefined
```

This means the mapbox-gl library now gets loaded and interpreted. However, the mapbox-gl code contains the line:

```
window.mapboxgl = something;
```

ES6-module scope does not have access to the browser 'window' object, so the code fails. See also [Is there an es6 module-scope equivalent to `window`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961255/is-there-an-es6-module-scope-equivalent-to-window).

For now, I am adding the HTML5 <script></script> and <link /> tags (see above) to the index.html of my project. This works, but the idea of components and modules is to load dependencies from inside those components and modules?

Comment: import './node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js'; should work, it will make the variable global tough...

Comment: maybe `import * as mapboxgl from ...`?

Comment: Both ```import 'module.js'```  and ```import * as mapboxgl from 'module.js'``` seem to do something more. However, the import now produces an Uncaught TypeError ```Cannot set property 'mapboxgl' of undefined```. This seems to occur inside the library with expression ```window.mapboxgl = ... ```. The global ```window``` object is not available in E6-module scope, so I should probably give up and wait for the mapbox-gl library to support ES6-modules? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961255/is-there-an-es6-module-scope-equivalent-to-window

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

With your original code to load script:

```
// load external mapbox-gl.js script
const mapboxgljs = document.createElement('script');
mapboxgljs.setAttribute('src', 'node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');
document.head.appendChild(mapboxgljs);
```

At this moment, if you use the instance provided by the script: `const map = new mapboxgl.Map(options)`

You will get error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined`

Reason: the script isn't loaded yet, so the instance `window.mapboxgl` is undefined.

Solution: You have to wait until the script finished loading, using event listener. Add this code into your loading script code:

```
mapboxgljs.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // mapboxgl is available here, do whatever you want
  const map = new mapboxgl.Map(options)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**For me the solution was to define the import without mustasch {}:**

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapboxgl'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
import("node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl");

// do my stuff with global dependency
```

or if import is slower than the code to be execute

```
import("node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl").then(() => {
    // do my stuff with global dependency
})
```